# how to work in excel download functionality in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, export-to-excel

Hi all i am using `angularjs` in mean stack i working with `excel` download functionality my need is when i click download button i need to download one excel sheet and that excel i mentioned the column names in one scope variable like $scope.Sno="S.No" just like that.These Scope variable should show as header of the excel sheet. How do this in `angularjs` if is it possible?

here i attached sample code what i am do means when click button excel will download and get the whole HTML table content using table ID

## code

```
 $scope.exportData = function () {
         var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('table2excel').innerHTML], {
             type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
         });
         saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
     };
```

Comment: i asked this is possible or not? @Claies

Comment: Now i updated my question apologize for that any suggestion links   to do this @Claies

Comment: i update my question @Claies

Comment: @Claies now my output is look like this how means whole table with will come in excel but my need is i give the column name from scope variable that columns only generate in excel now it's cleared?

Comment: yes now i only  constructed the table itself .now i need to hide the column c in downloding excel means how can i do @Claies

Comment: hi @Claies when i download the excel sheet right .if content is column a and column b known as sno name is their, means now i want hide column c in excel while time of downloading now clear?

Comment: ya finally i get the answer thank you so much it's not possible of excel customization right @Claies

Comment: @Claies your are woking with c#

Comment: eh?  what does c# have to do with this question?  you asked about angular and node here.

Comment: I'm completely confused.  Obviously I can't help you here, and you don't really seem like you want to improve your question, so I wish you good luck with figuring out your issue.

Comment: it's ok thanks for your supporting @Claies